# Update SQL table identify rows to the numbers of rows

Tags: sql

If I have SQL table with 5 rows and identity ID column.

```
RowName | ID
Row1    | 1
Row2    | 2
Row3    | 3
Row4    | 4
Row5    | 5
```

Let say that I delete row4

Then I add Row6 the id will be 6
But if I delete Row4 then
Row6 ID will remain 6
And Row5 ID will remain 5.

I want if I delete Row4
Row5 ID will update to ID 4
And Row6 update to ID 5

Comment: Change your approach/design.  The contract of the `ID` column only says that all values will be unique, and generally increasing.  If you need a sequence, then do something like add a timestamp column and use row number.

Comment: That sounds like a really strange thing to do.

Comment: You need to update each row with new value after deleting any row. Think of it and build a logic to do it.

Comment: That's a really, really bad idea.

Comment: Any chance the table will be referenced in a FK from the other table? Then just don't do it.

Comment: @Serg. or - even worse - referenced but without a FK.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with an identity row. You need to define "id" as a row without identity, and then you can delete and update. It's also a good idea to make this within a transaction. So the final SQL is:

```
begin transaction;
delete from tab where id = 4;
update tab set id = id-1 where id > 4;
commit;
```